# JSON.stringify Omite el 0 en la conversion de la cada de texto

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Buen dia, tengo el siguiente codigo AJAX. Estoy capturando un valor que tengo en un boton, es el siguiente:

```
 <button class="btn btn-primary mx-1 agregarcarrito" style="border-radius:15px;" data-idproducto="@Html.DisplayTextFor(m => m.ProductoCodigo)">
                    <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart "></i>
                    Añadir al Carrito
  </button>
```

El ajax es el siguiente: el valor correcto lo trae en consola y es 06501105 y ya en la conversion de JSON.STRINGIFY me omite el 0 que tiene al principio y asi es con todos los quei inician con 0. Alguien sabra el porque? de antemano gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Aclaraste mi duda, muchas gracias amigo. Saludos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tenemos dos opciones, ese valor es un número o es un string:

- Si es un número, Javascript lo interpretará como un número en base octal, por lo que no podrás ver ese número en el JSON tal cual.
- Si es un string, Javascript no quita el 0 inicial porque significaría modificarlo.

Demostración:

```js
const $elem= $('#ejemplo');
$elem.data('key2', 06501105); // OJO! el 0 inicial indica base octal, por lo que guarda realmente 1737285


console.log($elem.data('key1'));
console.log($elem.data('key2'));

console.log(JSON.stringify ({ dato1: $elem.data('key1'), dato2 : $elem.data('key2')}));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="ejemplo" data-key1="06501105"/>
```

Por otro lado, como te han enlazado en los comentarios, el formato JSON no permite números en una base distinta a la decimal y los ceros a la izquierda no están permitidos:

```js
try {
  console.log(JSON.parse('{"valor": 010}'));
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err.message);
}

try {
  console.log(JSON.parse('{"valor": "010"}'));
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err.message);
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo! Aclaraste mi duda y pode encontrar mi problema y asi mismo ya lo solucione... Saludos